# Does $\|u+v\|=\|u-v\|$ when orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Just want to confirm that if the subject is correct:
$$\|u+v\|^2=\|u-v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2 .$$

What do you think?
Thanks,
Li

Comment: in my view, yes

Comment: I think you mean $||u+v||^2 = ||u-v||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $\|u\pm v\| = \langle u,u \rangle \pm \langle u,v \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle$.

Comment: Use the definition $||x||^2 = x\cdot x$ with $x=u+v$ and then with $x=u-v$ and compare the two expressions. Finally use the condition for what it means that $u,v$ are orthogonal (in terms of $u\cdot v$) to complete the proof.

Comment: Yes it should be true.

Comment: Thanks all, the answers are helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ ( ||u+v||_2 )^2 =(u+v)(u+v)^{*}$$

${*}$ is hermitian sign, so this is true

since they are orthogonal, the $uv^{*}$ and $u^{*}v$ terms are zero

above equations also hold for negative one